# ISSUES with Monitor folder, consume WebService and send files via FTP Outbound channel

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-integration, spring-scheduled

I'm having bad time dealing with a simple application that must monitor a folder for new files, take each file and consume RESTful service ( one of my other apps) and send the response files using spring integration FTP Outbound channel adapter

It has following structure:

[image]

Initializer:

```
package com.ftpoutbound;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

import com.ftpoutbound.client.FtpoutboundApp;
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(FtpoutboundApp.class);
    }

}
```

I define beans in FtpoutboundApp:

```
package com.ftpoutbound.client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.expression.common.LiteralExpression;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.outbound.FtpMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.ftpoutbound.monitor.MonitorDirectory;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.ftpoutbound" })
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableScheduling
public class FtpoutboundApp implements ApplicationContextAware {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FtpoutboundApp.class);

    @Autowired
    private MonitorDirectory monitor;

    @Autowired
    MyGateway gateway;

    @Value("${remotedirectory}")
    private String remotedirectory;

    @Value("${remotehost}")
    private String remotehost;

    @Value("${remoteport}")
    private int remoteport;

    @Value("${remoteuser}")
    private String remoteuser;

    @Value("${remotepassword}")
    private String remotepassword;

    @Value("${outbound214sname}")
    private String outbound214sname;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FtpoutboundApp.class, args);
    }

    public void createGateway(File file214) {
        try {
            gateway.sendToFtp(file214);
            file214.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ERROR APP OUTBOUND\n");
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(remotehost);
        sf.setPort(remoteport);
        sf.setUsername(remoteuser);
        sf.setPassword(remotepassword);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(remotedirectory));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {

            @Override
            public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
                String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssssssss").format(new Date());
                return outbound214sname + "." + date + time;
            }
        });
        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "ftpChannel")
        void sendToFtp(File file);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void afterApplicationReady(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        try {
            logger.info("INICIO DE MONITOREO DE ARCHIVOS HG");
            monitor.startMonitoring();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR EN MONITOREO  DE FOLDER ENTRADA ARCHIVOS HG:\n" + e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("INTERRUPCIÓN EN MONITOREO  DE FOLDER ENTRADA ARCHIVOS HG:\n" + e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    }

}
```

The monitor started from the FtpoutboundApp:
I'm using SCHEDULED annotation since Watchservice was not working either

```
package com.ftpoutbound.monitor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ftpoutbound.client.FtpoutboundApp;
import com.ftpoutbound.restfulclient.httpPost;

@Component
public class MonitorDirectory {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MonitorDirectory.class);

    @Autowired
    private httpPost httppost;

    @Value("${inboundhgfilesfolder}")
    private String inboundhgfilesfolder;

    @Value("${inboundhgfilesfolderbak}")
    private String inboundhgfilesfolderbak;

    @Value("${hglin}")
    private String hglin;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void startMonitoring() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            listFiles();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ERROR MONITOREANDO FOLDER");
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    public void listFiles() throws Exception {
        File directory = new File(inboundhgfilesfolder);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList) {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if (file.isFile()) {
                readFile(fileName);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

        String hgFile = fileName.substring(0, 7);
        if (hgFile.equals(hglin)) {

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inboundhgfilesfolder + fileName);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = input.read()) != -1) {
                builder.append((char) ch);
            }
            try {
                httppost.get214fromRestful(builder.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("ERROR EN POST REQUEST DESDE APP OUTBOUND:\n" + e);
            }
        }
        moveFile(fileName);
    }

    public void moveFile(String fileName) {

        Path source = Paths.get(inboundhgfilesfolder + fileName);
        Path newdir = Paths.get(inboundhgfilesfolderbak + fileName);
        try {
            Files.move(source, newdir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR MOVIENDO ARCHIVO:\n" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTTPclient that consumes the RESTful app

```
package com.ftpoutbound.restfulclient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.ftpoutbound.client.FtpoutboundApp;

@Component
public class httpPost {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(httpPost.class);

    @Value("${restful214url}")
    private String restful214url;

    @Value("${outbound214sfolder}")
    private String outbound214sfolder;

    @Autowired
    private FtpoutboundApp ftpoutbound;

    public void get214fromRestful(String hgfile) throws Exception {
        logger.info("OBTENIENDO 214");
        logger.info("DIRECCION" + restful214url);
        logger.info("ARCHIVO" + hgfile);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(restful214url, hgfile, String.class);

        File file = createFile214local(result.toString());
        logger.info("RESULTADO DE POST:");
        logger.info(result.toString());

        ftpoutbound.createGateway(file);

    }

    private File createFile214local(String hgfile) {

        logger.info("ESCRIBIENDO 214");
        File file = new File(outbound214sfolder + "214.tmp");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(hgfile);
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR ESCRIBIENDO FILE:\n->" + e);
        }

        return file;
    }

}
```

but the app seems not working, it freezes before consuming the RESTful in:

```
            logger.info("OBTENIENDO 214");
            logger.info("DIRECCION" + restful214url);
            logger.info("ARCHIVO" + hgfile);
```

I noticed these lines are printed twice in the log, still not sure if this is a threads issue or what causes the APP to not even finish the deployment in the server, I have another similar App (except that one doesn't consume RESTful) and it works OK, another FTPInbound channel Adapter and it works OK, but I have some days figuring what I'm missing or **What's the best way to do this.**

Believe me, Help will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: First step, as always, is to enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`; you will get many diagnostic log records. If you stop getting logs, take a thread dump with jstack or visualvm.

Comment: thanks Gary, I'm doing debugs but does my app have good logic: defining ftpoutboun beans -> start monitoring with @EventListener and from the monitor consume RESTful and then call -> ftpoutbound.createGateway(file) to send out the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that 
my outbound channel configuration class was implementing `ApplicationContextAware` and it was causing the RestTemplate to freezes the App when consuming my Microservices App, so I changed to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and implement `WebApplicationInitializer`and it worked.